# RedisSerializer handling java.util.Optional (Spring Data Redis)

Tags: java, redis, spring-data, spring-data-redis

Hi I want to use Redis as a cache provider but unfortunately the redis serializer (Json, String) do not support java.util.Optional

I think some lines of code explain it better:

```
@Cacheable("test)
public Optional<Account> getAccount(String accountId){
  // ... call to some service or rest api
}
```

Optional cannot be serialized by the default java serializer and I haven't figured out yet how to tell the JsonSerializer to handle Optional. How is this going to work? Get rid of Optional doesn't really sound like an option to me.

Answer (score 2):

### In short:

There's no out-of-the-box support.

### Explanation

Spring Cache (which is part of `spring-context`) stores natively the values that are returned by `@Cacheable` methods. This works fine when using in-memory caches like `HashMap`, Guava or EhCache (without replication). There is no further unboxing. `Optional` can have different semantics within caching. `Optional.isPresent() == false` can mean either the value is not in the cache or it could mean there's no value available at all.

There are however two alternatives:

1. Create an own serializer (based on the JDK serializer) where you implement special treatment for `Optional<T>`
2. Create your own `CacheInterceptor` based on `CacheAspectSupport` but then you need to adjust proxy wiring and most probably you need to disable the default `CacheInterceptor`

HTH, Mark

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. Really unfortunate though :) I am considering to use AspectJ this (Putting @Cacheable on a private method which wraps the result into an Optional) This might be an option too I think.

Comment: @jeven I also did like you suggest. Really bad!